# Widget dialogue that creates new nodes - Adobe CQ5

Tags: servlets, widget, aem

I'm trying to create an edit widget for a page that asks for various details and then stores those details as properties of a newly created node.

So for instance:
Make
Model
Mileage

and I want to store those as a node under a parent node in /content/cars or something similar.

How can I get a widget to create a new node under /content/cars and store those properties there?

Do I have to send the data to a servlet that I create? Or are there options to enable this?

Answer (score 2):

What you'd probably want to do is include a component in the containing page at the path you want the nodes created.

For example, if you have a page /content/cars, and you wanted to create a Chevy node under there at /content/cars/jcr:content/chevy, you'd include the component with this fragment:

`<cq:include path="chevy" resourceType="myapp/components/manufacturer" />`

This would include the content and render it and allow it to be edited with the component located at /apps/myapp/components/manufacturer.

If you want you can even have the node be at an absolute path, for example if you want to reference the content at /content/data/cars/chevy on another page you could use:

`<cq:include path="/content/data/cars/chevy" resourceType="myapp/components/manufacturer" />`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the provided cheatsheet from Adobe:

http://dev.day.com/content/ddc/blog/2008/07/cheatsheet/_jcr_content/par/download/file.res/cheatsheet.pdf

The default Sling POST servlet recognizes what JCR properties to update by examining the 'name' attribute of the input tags that are included in the ExtJS dialogs.  To configure a widget like a textfield or dropdownfield to target and update a specific property, you will need to specify the property's name in the widget definition.

For example, if you are using an XML file to define your page dialog at /content/cars and you wished for there to be widgets that let users store model, make, and year to the jcr:content node of the cars page.  Your associated dialog definition would contain nodes that look like:

```
<make
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="textfield"
    name="./make"/>
<model
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="textfield"
    name="./model"/>
<year
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="textfield"
    name="./year"/>
```

To change the widget type you would adjust the **xtype** attribute and to change the property to target you would adjust the **name** attribute.  Note that it is relative from the content node of the page/component where the dialog is being invoked (in this case, relative from /content/cars/jcr:content).

Another example: say you wanted to store the value of make to a property called 'make' on a node like /content/cars/jcr:content/brands, then your definition would look like:

```
<make
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="textfield"
    name="./brands/make"/>
```

For a reference on available xtypes, check out:
http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Add this js function to your pages

```
function doOpenDlg(url, path) {
    var d = CQ.WCM.getDialog(url);
    var reloadPage = true;
    if(d) {
        if( reloadPage ) {
            d.success = function(form, action) {
                CQ.Util.reload(CQ.WCM.getContentWindow());
            };
        }
        d.show();
        d.loadContent(path);
    }
}
```

and then create a dialog like file. In this exemple :

/apps/myapp/components/page/mypage/myxmlfile.xml

then you can open a dialog matching this file with :

```
 <input type="button" value="Open my dialog" style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;"
           onclick="doOpenDlg('/apps/myapp/components/page/mypage/myxmlfile.infinity.json', '<%=currentNode.getPath() %>');" />
```

with this, your dialog data will be saved in the currentNode, but you can put any path you want.